# how to use vtkImageReSlice?

Tags: python-3.x, vtk

I am trying to use vtkImageReSlicer to extract a 2d slice from a 3d
vtkImageData object. But I can't seem to get the recipe right. Am I doing it right?
I am also a bit confused about ResliceAxes Matrix. Does it represent a cutting plane? If
I move the ReSliceAxes origin will it also move the cutting plane? When I
call Update on the vtkImageReSlicer, the program crashes. But when I don't
call it, the output is empty.

Here's what I have so far.

```
#my input is any vtkactor that contains a closed curve of type vtkPolyData
ShapePolyData = actor.GetMapper().GetInput()
boundingBox = ShapePolyData.GetBounds()
for i in range(0,6,2):
     delta = boundingBox[i+1]-boundingBox[i]
     newBoundingBox.append(boundingBox[i]-0.5*delta)
     newBoundingBox.append(boundingBox[i+1]+0.5*delta)

voxelizer = vtk.vtkVoxelModeller()
voxelizer.SetInputData(ShapePolyData)
voxelizer.SetModelBounds(newBoundingBox)
voxelizer.SetScalarTypeToBit()
voxelizer.SetForegroundValue(1)
voxelizer.SetBackgroundValue(0)
voxelizer.Update()

VoxelModel =voxelizer.GetOutput()

ImageOrigin = VoxelModel.GetOrigin()
slicer = vtk.vtkImageReslice()
#Am I setting the cutting axis here. x axis set at 1,0,0 , y axis at 0,1,0 and z axis at 0,0,1
slicer.SetResliceAxesDirectionCosines(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)
#if I increase the z value, will the cutting plane move up?
slicer.SetResliceAxesOrigin(ImageOrigin[0],ImageOrigin[1],ImageOrigin[2])
slicer.SetInputData(VoxelModel)
slicer.SetInterpolationModeToLinear()
slicer.SetOutputDimensionality(2)
slicer.Update() #this makes the code crash

voxelSurface = vtk.vtkContourFilter()
voxelSurface.SetInputConnection(slicer.GetOutputPort())
voxelSurface.SetValue(0, .999)

voxelMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
voxelMapper.SetInputConnection(voxelSurface.GetOutputPort())
voxelActor = vtk.vtkActor()
voxelActor.SetMapper(voxelMapper)
Renderer.AddActor(voxelActor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `vtkImageReslice`, but I have used `vtkExtractVOI` for `vtkImageData`, which allows you to achieve a similar result, I think. Here is your example modified with the latter, instead:

```
ImageOrigin = VoxelModel.GetOrigin()
slicer = vtk.vtkExtractVOI()
slicer.SetInputData(VoxelModel)
#With the setVOI method you can define which slice you want to extract
slicer.SetVOI(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zslice, zslice)
slicer.SetSampleRate(1, 1, 1)
slicer.Update()

voxelSurface = vtk.vtkContourFilter()
voxelSurface.SetInputConnection(slicer.GetOutputPort())
voxelSurface.SetValue(0, .999)

voxelMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
voxelMapper.SetInputConnection(voxelSurface.GetOutputPort())
voxelActor = vtk.vtkActor()
voxelActor.SetMapper(voxelMapper)
Renderer.AddActor(voxelActor)
```